# Converting bytes to bits and then to Mbits

Tags: hard-drive

If you have a 100 50KB files that is saved on your hard disk per second, I want to figure out how many Mbits per second this is.

So please correct me if I am wrong:

= 50 * 8 * 1000
= 400 000 bits per second

400 000 bits per second is how many Mbits per second (mega bits per second)?

Is it .4 Mbps transfer rate then?

Comment: Usually if people/Microsoft speaks of "50 KB" the mean "50 KiB" which means 50 * 1024 bytes.

Comment: 400 Kbps is 40% of 1 Mbps.  This would be 0.40 Mbps

Comment: @Robert : No, and that's why binary prefixes were created. When retailers say "50 kB" they **really** mean 50kB = 50,000 bytes. But people believe it is "50 kiB" which is equal to 50 * 1024 B = 51,200 bytes = 51.2 kB. Binary prefixes were created to avoid this confusion (where people get less memory than they think).

Comment: @air-dex: But here we are talking about files of 50KB size and common OS I know usually show the value as KiB even if it is labeled "KB".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For conversion between b**i**ts and b**y**tes, it is easy too :

> 1 byte = 1B = 8 bits = 8b

For bits, it is the [International System of units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units) which uses decimal prefixes. So it is easy to understand :

> 1Mb = 1 Mega-bits = 1.000.000 bits

However, the decimal prefixes of International System of units must not be counfounded with the [binary prefixes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix) system. So do not rely on Robert's comment under the question.

---

So in your case :

```
50 kB = 50,000 B = 50,000 * 8 b = 400,000 b = 400 kb = 0.4 Mb
```